# Linking elements of an array with an offset

Tags: arrays, algorithm, traversal

**The following is an excerpt from "Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs" by Niklaus Wirth, chapter "1.7. THE RECORD STRUCTURE":**

In a further example we assume that (possibly in order to find them more quickly) certain groups of persons in the array *a* are linked together. The linking information is represented by an additional component of the record structure *Person*, named *link*. The links connect records into a linear chain so that each person's successor and predecessor may be found easily. The interesting property of this linking technique is that the chain may be traversed in both directions on the basis of a single number stored in each record. The technique works as follows.

Assume that the indices of three consecutive members of the chain are *i*<sub>k-1</sub>, *i*<sub>k</sub>, *i*<sub>k+i</sub>. The link value of the *k*th member is chosen to be *i*<sub>k+1</sub>—*i*<sub>k-1</sub>. Traversing the chain in the forward direction, *i*<sub>k+1</sub> is determined from the two current index variables *x = i<sub>k-1</sub>*, and *y = i<sub>k</sub>* as:

*i<sub>k+1</sub> = x+a[y].link*

whereas traversing the chain in the backward direction, *i*<sub>k-1</sub> is determined from *x = i<sub>k+1</sub>*, and *y = i<sub>k</sub>* as:

*i<sub>k-1</sub> = x - a[y].link*

An example is linking all persons of equal sex in a table:

```
Index  First Name Sex  Link
-----  ---------- ---  ----
1      Carolyn    F    2
2      Chris      M    2
3      Tina       F    5
4      Robert     M    3
5      Jonathan   M    3
6      Jennifer   F    5
7      Raytheon   M    5
8      Mary       F    3
9      Anne       F    1
10     Mathias    M    3
```

**I cannot understand how linking works.  Let's say that we want to traverse the chain in the forward direction, by starting with *y = i<sub>k</sub> = a[1]*.  Since we have no previous *i*<sub>k-1</sub> element, what is the starting value of *x*? I have tried starting with either *x = 0* or *x = 1*, but both lead to wrong sequences. What if we want to traverse the chain in the backward direction?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It assumes that you start on the lowest-indexed element in the chain if traversing forwards, or the highest-indexed element if traversing backwards. These elements have their link values set so that the initial value for x is equal to the current index, y. For example, traversing the females:

Traversing forwards, starting with Carolyn...

i<sub>k</sub> = y = 1

i<sub>k-1</sub> = x = 1 (initial guess for x is the same as y)

i<sub>k+1</sub> = x + a[y].link = 1 + 2 = 3

...the person at index 3 is Tina. Success!

Traversing backwards, starting with Anne...

i<sub>k</sub> = y = 9

i<sub>k-1</sub> = x = 9 (initial guess for x is the same as y)

i<sub>k+1</sub> = x - a[y].link = 9 - 1 = 8

...the person at index 8 is Mary. Success!

I don't think you can start at an arbitrary position in the middle of the table with this method. You can only traverse forwards from the start, or backwards from the end.

---

**Edit:** For completeness, the blokes:

Traversing forwards, starting with Chris...

i<sub>k</sub> = y = 2

i<sub>k-1</sub> = x = 2 (initial guess for x is the same as y)

i<sub>k+1</sub> = x + a[y].link = 2 + 2 = 4

... The person at index 4 is Robert.

Traversing backwards, starting with Mathias...

i<sub>k</sub> = y = 10

i<sub>k-1</sub> = x = 10 (initial guess for x is the same as y)

i<sub>k+1</sub> = x - a[y].link = 10 - 3 = 7

... The person at index 7 is Raytheon.